Openrewrite migrate static imported assertThrows to assertJ doesn't work
i want to migrate unit-tests from junit and harmcrest to assertJ.
Most things work with the recipe
activeRecipe("org.openrewrite.java.testing.assertj.JUnitToAssertj")
but some doesn't e.g. assertThrows is not migrated from junit to assertj.
What might be the reason for that?
Im using the gradle plugin from assertj (Version 6.11.2) and    rewrite("org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-testing-frameworks:2.6.0") as a dependency
I run ./gradlew rewriteRun and expected it to migrate all junit method calls to assertJ, but it didn't for multiple assertions and for all assertThrows , assertDoesNotThrow
Example for not migrated assertions:
@Test
@DisplayName("resolve contract state - no interest matches ref")
void testResolveContractStateNoInterest() throws ApplicationException {
   // given
   Contract contractMock = createContractMock(false, false);
   mockContractApi(contractMock);

   InsuranceSuspensionView suspensionMock = createSuspensionMock(false);
   mockAmendmentApi(suspensionMock);

   // when
   ContractRequiredServiceImpl classUnderTest = spy(new ContractRequiredServiceImpl(sc));
   var exception = assertThrows(ContractException.class,
         () -> classUnderTest.resolveContractState(GIVEN_CONTRACT_REF, UNKNOWN_INTEREST_REF, GIVEN_BUSINESS_DATE));

   // then
   assertThat(exception.getError().getMessageId()).isEqualTo("My Custom Error Message");
}

The assertThrows is statically imported with import static org.junit.Assert.assertThrows; and is not migrated.
It doesn't work with either recipe.
rewrite {
   activeRecipe("org.openrewrite.java.testing.assertj.JUnitToAssertj")
   activeRecipe("org.openrewrite.java.testing.assertj.JUnitAssertThrowsToAssertExceptionType")
}

Another simple example, which also can't be migrated:
@Test
void mapKorrekturgrundReasonThrows() {
   // when
   Executable executable = () -> IccTypeMapper.INSTANCE.mapKorrekturgrundReason(null);

   // then
   assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, executable);
}


Sorry to hear about your issue! Do you see any reference in the logs about missing type information, or parse exceptions that might affect OpenRewrite's ability to convert your test class?
We do have a org.openrewrite.java.testing.assertj.JUnitAssertThrowsToAssertExceptionType that should perform that migration:

https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/testing/assertj/junitassertthrowstoassertexceptiontype
https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-testing-frameworks/blob/7ba17bbbfb2c9f5437a377d4e022c101a31579e2/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/java/testing/assertj/JUnitAssertThrowsToAssertExceptionType.java#L30-L40

It might help if you can share an example that's not migration; ideally in the form of a unit test as seen here:

https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-testing-frameworks/blob/53cfd4cdd4fbcf472b3cb7f0e00d217cea31d6a4/src/test/java/org/openrewrite/java/testing/assertj/JUnitAssertThrowsToAssertExceptionTypeTest.java#L38-L68

That helps us replicate your usage pattern and then codify that as a recipe step to migrate.

thanks for the comment. I extended my issue and added a testcase where the assertThrows is not migrated..

Ah thanks for adding that example! In this case I think it's the mocking library to trips up the type information available on assertThrows, which that fails to match & convert. :/

i added another example which can't be migrated. That one has no call to other method besides the tested method..

Thanks! I've reported that case as a possible improvement:

https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-testing-frameworks/issues/511
